# String comparison failing due to encoding

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, python-2.x

I have the following string comparison that behaves as intended:

```
u'release V13.0.0: (Alumin\xadium) improved API' == u"release V13.0.0: (Alumin­ium) improved API"
```

(Be aware that there is a soft-hyphen between Alumin-ium that is not represented here on the second string)

My problem is how to reproduce this comparison when using variables instead of literal strings, since using `unicode()` has this output:

```
unicode(rows[38][0]) == ("release V13.0.0: (Alumin­ium) improved API")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)
```

EDIT: First string comes from a database and second string comes from Gitlab API.

Comment: `unicode()` can convert normal characters but no escaped chars. You need to write/use a other/own converter if want to transform is firtly to normal chars and then to unicode.

Answer (score 0):

this part: `"(Alumin\xadium)"` has an unwanted escape character, if the original string was in python code then it would create an unwanted escape sequence of `'\xad'`. replace it with `'\\xad'` to make it a literal `r'\xad'`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the rows are encoded as latin-1, so they must be decoded to unicode before comparing:

```python
>>> encoded = u'release V13.0.0: (Alumin\xadium) improved API'.encode('latin-1')
>>> unicode(encoded)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> unicode(encoded, 'latin-1')
u'release V13.0.0: (Alumin\xadium) improved API'
```